# Import format template .ai to a .qpt template

Tags: layouts

I work for a company that uses adobe illustrator(AI) for layout-issues.
When I make maps, the workflow is first do my work in QGIS, then pre-layout in QGIS-Layout, export to .svg and then finalize the layout in AI. Sometimes it is a bit annoying, since I do some of the work twice...

There is template for online publications, that we use in AI. Is there a possibility to transform the .ai-template to a .qpt format? Or somehow import the .ai-template?

[image: the original template in AI]

[image: after export to .svg, it is just an image]

Comment: Export the layout as SVG from AI, then load the SVG into the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn´t work for me. The template contents different layers and the qgis layouter imports it as image, so I don´t see a way to ungroup the SVG and use the single elements I need.

Comment: Please include relevant details, if possible also a screenshot, in your question.